# Use SQL INSERT to Create Directories with FileTable

Tags: t-sql, filestream, sql-server-2012, filetable

Is there a way to create directories in a [FileTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929144.aspx) without using File I/O APIs? Is it just as simple as creating a SQL INSERT statement?

This is my first experience with SQL Server 2012 and I'm not familiar with the limits of the `FileTable` from within SQL Server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following worked for me. Hopefully this helps out someone else.

```sql
INSERT INTO FileTable0 (name,is_directory,is_archive) VALUES ('Directory', 1, 0);
```

- You should also check out [Bob Beauchemin's Techdays 2012 video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechDays/Techdays-2012-the-Netherlands/2270) for more details on `FileStream` and its evolution into `FileTable`.

Comment: This is partially right. This only covers adding a directory in the root. Adding a subdirectory, or creating a path without any of the parent directories created, are not handled by this.

Comment: @Rhyous - you are correct, for [adding subdirectories see this related SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10485978/175679). You must have a parent defined before you can create any children. You could implement a simple algorithm to do the behavior you are seeking using a combination of this post and the other and checking whether a given directory exists already.

Comment: Thanks. Found that yesterday. I am taking this and making some SQL functions. Maybe I'll share them on GitHub when I am done.